# Inject Css into iframe from third party

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, oas

Can we inject bunch of CSS files into an iframe from a third party like OAS which is hosting ads? If it is possible an example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By using jQuery selectors, you should be able to do that. However there should not be any restriction on iframe contents (i.e it should be from same domain)

For HTML update:

`$('iframe').contents().find("body")` will get you body object

`$('iframe').contents().find("head")` will get you header object. You can add style here

Please refer this Tutorial for details

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe--net-22826

and this

https://github.com/NETTUTS/Inject-HTML-and-CSS-into-iFrame/blob/master/iframe.html

If the iframe is from different domain then it is not possible due to http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: [Consider adding more content to your answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)

Comment: This is example of the iframe on the same domain....I need some insight on whether CSS file can be injected into an iframe from a third party

Comment: Not possible if it is from different domain. Updated the answer